# Icon for EXE file got cached in Explorer and doesn't update after a rebuild

Tags: c#, windows, icons

I have written a simple application in VS 2015 and published the build.

I have applied the icon and every thing works fine. However, I have decided to change the icon to a better looking one. The projects publishes OK and it contains a new icon in the bin\Release folder.

However, when I copy the same exe file onto the desktop, it displays the old icon. It appears OK on my windows laptop...

I have cleared the icon cache file and restarted the machine. Stopped and started the explorer.

Using windows server 2012 VM machine.

Any clues? [image]

Comment: Yeah, that old icon got cached somehow. I've seen this before, on various versions of Windows, starting with Windows 7. I generally have had success deleting the icon cache and restarting. Sometimes you also need to launch the application through that shortcut. But it doesn't always work. It isn't worth pulling your hair out over. The client's machine will get the right icon, even if your dev box is stale.

Comment: I have located thumbanil cache files as well but cannot delete them. Oh well I will leave it as is then if there is no obvious way. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Google "reset shell icon cache".  Use superuser.com if that doesn't help.

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: To make it clear, it only happens on the desktop not everywhere else so its not entire explorer is effected.The icon on the right is correct and the one on the left is wrong.

Comment: I have generated the exe with different name and the icon is now correct on my desktop??!! it looks like the icon got assigned and cached with the name... really strange